# Social Media JavaScript (buttons) not getting along Google+, Facebook, YouTube etc

Tags: javascript, php, facebook-graph-api, youtube, google-plus-one

I built a quotation mashup. I added a bunch of social sharing buttons. It worked.

I decide to add Google+ and it does not get along with the other JavaScript / HTML. So I commented out all the other social sharing buttons and the Google+ button still doesn't work. Then I try a different quotation, one without a YouTube video it works, one with a YouTube video does not show a Google+ button. That is what I have discovered.

Switching YouTube display code does help, but Facebook like doesn't seem to work now, but Facebook Share does and I'm not 100% sold on my OpenGraph and thus Google+ meta data. Facebook updated their button recently and now I find 'Share' works better than 'Like'. Both can be tracked in Google Analytics in theory. I would like the quotation to appear in the description, that was working for Facebook but I can't get that to happen on Google+. Perhaps I need more meta data. I changed to og:type article that seems to help.

[Quotation Collection](http://www.muschamp.ca/Muskie/quotations.html)

[Quotation with Video](http://www.muschamp.ca/Muskie/favouriteQuotationsMashup.php?q=0)

[Quotation with no YouTube Video](http://www.muschamp.ca/Muskie/favouriteQuotationsMashup.php?q=94)

I use PHP to build the JavaScript but the Google+ button as far as I can tell gets everything from the metadata. There also might be something wrong with my metadata as I don't do it as cleanly as I do on [this page](http://nurgle.muschamp.ca/whatIsNurgle.html) I've revised much of my meta data to try and get my shares to look their best. I need last.fm to provide bigger images or to revisit what I can get out of the wikipedia.

I got all four buttons well 5 social sharing buttons working on my blog, but I used two plugins, the Pinterest button is probably not tracked by Google Analytics but the other four are. I'm pretty sure I almost had it working last night, scarily the li tag seems to make a difference if you use divs and a bunch of CSS it seems to work better than using a list with one button in each item.

```
<!-- Professional Share Plugin--><div class="ProfessionalShareBox"><div class="PSBtn"><script type="IN/Share" data-counter="right" data-showzero="true" data-onsuccess="LinkedInShare"></script></div><div class="PSBtn"><a href="https://twitter.com/share" onclick="javascript:_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','outbound-article','http://twitter.com']);" class="twitter-share-button" data-lang="en" data-via="MuskieMcKay"></a></div><div class="PSBtn"><div class="g-plusone" data-size="medium"></div></div><div class="PSBtn"><div class="fb-like" data-href="http://blog.muschamp.ca/2013/11/24/back-from-mexico/" data-send="false" data-width="90" data-layout="button_count" data-show-faces="false" data-action="recommend"></div></div></div><div id="fb-root"></div><div class='yarpp-related yarpp-related-none'>
```

I might switch to not using an ordered list of buttons and I also might steal from arguments from Ken's plugin seeing as I already gave him advice on how I would do it. ;-) Twitter Cards FTW!

Comment: I've got everything working except Facebook like. It seems I can't like something more than once or even at all from my own website, but I can share it many times...

Comment: Google's expandto doesn't work when you select top, at least not in Safari. I waste so much time debugging crap that isn't even my bug when I use all these social buttons. The good news is they all kinda work, Facebook being the exception and Google Analytics seems to track them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my basic problem. I changed how I was including YouTube videos, switching from probably the iFrame based include to the object include. Now I need to tweak my meta data to get it to display even better in Google+. I also tweaked my OpenGraph and Twitter Card meta data and am trying to find larger images through various APIs. My best effort at this can be seen in [this blog post](http://blog.muschamp.ca/2013/10/02/tracking-social-media-button-clicks-in-google-analytics/).

Comment: Damn everything seems to work but the Facebook Like button, why can't all these social sharing buttons get along?

Comment: The other quirk I discovered when I added Google Analytics tracking to a Pinterest button on a static page and a div too it renders differently in Safari….

Comment: I tried switching the style of the Facebook like button, apparently there at least four ways of doing that...